# hyperref-langpatches.def file not found in rmarkdown pdf knitting

Tags: pdftex, rmarkdown

I tried to compile a pdf in rmarkdon but the error shows hyperref-langpatches.def file not found. However, I can generate the pdf using the .tex file generated during the process.

Comment: the file is rather new. Perhaps you need to update a file name data base somewhere. Which tex system is used by rmarkdown?

Comment: I use MacTex. Do you have any idea which file should be updated. Thanks!

Comment: sorry I have no idea. Try to find some log-files so that you can check what rmarkdown is using, and if it is different to the other tex system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same error message while knitting an RMarkdown document.

Running `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` in the R Console solved the problem for me. It is recommended in the [troubleshooting page](https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging) of the R package `tinytex()`.

I hope it works for you too!